# MIME-Type for .css.br?

Tags: mime-types, brotli

What's the correct MIME-Type for .css.br files?
For ".css" it's "text/css" and for ".js.br" it's "application/x-br" (at least it's working for me). But what to use for ".css.br"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure the question makes sense and I am not sure what you mean when you say "at least it's working for me"?

The mime-type indicates the file type. If the file ends in .br then the file type is a brotli file - no matter whether it's a brotli compressed css or a brotli compressed js file.

It doesn't look like there is an [officially registered brotli mime-type](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml), though a quick Google shows ["application/x-br"](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/brotli/file$20format%7Csort:relevance/brotli/8ZOp4gPyKAA/ZL-P5qSOCQAJ) has been suggested as has [application/brotli](https://github.com/google/brotli/issues/299).

If you are pre-compressing files and want to send them from a web server to the client, then you should send them as .css files (not .css.br) and set the appropriate HTTP Headers:

```
content-encoding:br
content-type:text/css; charset=utf-8
```

And similarly for JavaScript files.

Precompression is just a way of saving your web server the trouble of compressing on the fly, but whether it's a precompressed file, or an on-fly compressed file shouldn't result in a difference to what is delivered to the browser.

Comment: Hi Barry, I had to register "br" files with "application/x-br" so IIS is able to serve them (IIS does not serve content with unknown MIME-Type). My current problem is, that the "css.br" files are served but "misinterpreted" by the browser. I tried it with a MIME-Type of "application/x-br" (then they get decompressed but not used correctly - no CSS formatting applied) and when I user "text/css" they don't get decompressed at all (err:....).

Comment: You register the original mime-types (e.g. text/css), rewrite the URLs to strip out the .br part, add a content-encoding response header and turn off dynamic compression. See this post for some details: https://answers.unity.com/questions/847635/correctly-configuring-iis7-to-serve-gzipped-conten.html. So as I said your question as it was stated did not make sense as there is no .css.br mime-type. I’m amazed your solution worked for .js.br files.